# c# - codebehind div style change not being rendered

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a `div` of the form

```
<div id="mydiv" runat="server" style="display:none"></div>
```

In my code behind, I attempt to change the `display` to `block` by

```
mydiv.Style["display"] = "block";
```

When I view the source code after the piece of code above is run, the **page source** reflects the change (i.e. the div's display is set to block) but the **visible page** does not. How can I get my page to show the `div`?

Comment: if `visible = block` then div is visible, unless div parent is hidden, explore the html to see why is not showing. OTOH, without content your div may seems to be invisible since default width and height is 0px

Comment: try using the inspector of your browser (right click -> inspect element in Chrome) and take a look at the CSS rules being applied to the div. Turn some of the rules on/off and you may find another CSS rule is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your code `mydiv.Style["display"] = "block";`? I just test it in Page_Load,and in the view page,it displayed,and the code in page source is this

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:block;">12345</div>
```

I set innerhtml to have a good view